# Is there a generic word or short phrase for "while taking into account both the [probability/amount] and the [effect size]"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, the word could be used like this:

-This decision will likely help, but it is a [foobar] bad choice: The result of the decision is most likely positive, but if it does end up negative it will be so strongly negative that this outweighs the gains even so.

Comment: *A [**risk matrix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_matrix) is a matrix that is used during risk assessment to define the level of risk by considering the category of **probability or likelihood** against the category of **consequence severity**.*

Comment: That's not usable as an adjective. I am looking for a quick, concise way to express the idea in a sentence, without having to start another sentence to explain where the topic falls on a risk matrix.

Comment: I wasn't really presenting that link as an *answer*. But it occurred to me that if there *was* a suitable term for your exact context, it would probably be mentioned somewhere on that Wikipedia page. I didn't notice any useful words there myself though - all I came away with was the impression that so far as risk assessment professionals are concerned, using the "risk matrix" approach is usually A Bad Idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is called a "long tail problem". It is a very general term in management circles (very loosely defined). Statisticians seem to be fighting a loosing fight to keep their formal definition of the term in play.

> In business, the term long tail is applied to rank-size distributions or rank-frequency distributions (primarily of popularity), which often form power laws and are thus long-tailed distributions in the statistical sense.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail

See also heavy tail - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution

*Kurtosis* is the term describing the tailedness of a distribution, usually quantified as the forth moment of the data set.

Distributions with big tails (kurtosis > 3) are said to be leptokurtic. I wouldn't use that last one at the watercooler though, unless you are in a statistics or economic research facility.

> Is there a generic word or short phrase for “while taking into account both the [probability/amount] and the [effect size]”

Yes. "Considering the long tail on the negative side, the risks still outweigh the gains."

> This decision will likely help, but it is a [foobar] bad choice

This decision has a high likelihood of helping, but suffers from a long tail on the negative side.

It is idiomatic to refer to, or caution against, being blind to the long tail. That thanks to the work of Nassim Taleb. In effect, he has single-handedly given us a common language for talking about this. Read his books.

Comment: Thanks! This is not an exact answer since I was hoping for a single word/adjective, but it is still a useful phrase that can be used to shorten these sorts of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

The downside outweighs any chance of gain. I do not think that there is a single word that encompasses that.